# How to animate the width change of a flex element with max-width: 'fit-content'

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially, I am making an application where I have two children in a flexbox, each with the flex attribute set to a certain value. However, I also set the max-width of the first child to be "fit-content." The problem is, when the content of the 1st child changes, the width will automatically stretch. I want the change in width to be animated.

I have included an example below. When you click show more, it will change the content of the 1st child, thus stretching it.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  if (btn.textContent === "Show More") {
    btn.textContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida, elit a semper ornare, velit odio imperdiet mauris, a volutpat."
  } else {
    btn.textContent = "Show More"
  }
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child1 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: fit-content;
  background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child1">
    <button id="btn">Show More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript to get the final width and transition to that from the current width. Css requires a known value for a transition and 'fit-content' is not a fixed value.